# How to make instances of a class in Smalltalk?

Tags: oop, constructor, smalltalk, visual-age

I'm new in Smalltalk (VisualAge environment) and I try to make a class that counts number of her instances. Unfortunately something dosen't work when I override the 'new' method. This is my class code:

```
Object subclass: #TestClassB
    instanceVariableNames: 'niceVariable '
    classVariableNames: 'InstanceCounter '
    poolDictionaries: ''!

!TestClassB class publicMethods !

initWithNiceParameter: parameter

    |testClassBInstance|

    testClassBInstance:= self new.
    ^(testClassBInstance niceVariable: parameter)!

new
    super new.
    InstanceCounter isNil
        ifTrue: [InstanceCounter := 0] 
        ifFalse: [InstanceCounter := InstanceCounter + 1].
    ^self
    ! !

!TestClassB publicMethods !

niceVariable: anObject
    "Save the value of niceVariable."
    niceVariable := anObject.
! !
```

I'd like to create new object with 'initWithNiceParameter' message:

```
TestClassB initWithNiceParameter: 'my super string'
```

But all I get is error:

```
TestClassB does not understand niceVariable:
```

It's because 'TestClassB' is also an object and seems it has no 'niceVariable' setter.

Do you have any idea how to create objects, when 'new' method is overrided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of your method `new` returns `self`. The value of `self` there is the class TestClassB because `new` is a class method and `self` in a class method is the class itself.

You should return the object that got created by sending `super new`:

```
new
   |instance|
   instance := super new.
   InstanceCounter isNil
       ifTrue: [InstanceCounter := 0] 
       ifFalse: [InstanceCounter := InstanceCounter + 1].
   ^instance
```

or shorter:

```
new
    InstanceCounter isNil
       ifTrue: [InstanceCounter := 0] 
       ifFalse: [InstanceCounter := InstanceCounter + 1].
   ^super new
```

Comment: While we're improving, let's initialize InstanceCounter to zero in a class-side #initialize and remove the branching completely ;)

Comment: Would 'TestClassB allInstances size' not suffice?

Comment: @SeanDeNigris what do you mean with #initialize and removing branching? I created this method (it's class-side method as same as #new), it overrides #initialize from Object class, but it isn't automatically called by creating new object.

Comment: @BobNemec 'TestClassB allInstances size' allways gives me 1 (SmallInteger)

Comment: @user3452568 It's too hard to explain in a comment. I'll show you in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Slightly OT, but the #ifTrue:ifFalse is unnecessarily complex. The Smalltalk way to initialize class-level variables is in a class-side #initialize* like so:

```
TestClassB class>>#initialize
   InstanceCounter := 0
```

Now, when you load TestClassB into the system, InstanceCounter will be initialized and you can simplify from [Johan's short version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26182353/424245) to:

```
TestClassB class>>#new
   InstanceCounter := InstanceCounter + 1.
   ^super new
```

- or lazily

Comment: Shouldn't be `TestClassB>>#new` a class-side method? Like this: `TestClassB class>>#new`?

Answer (score 0):

I was confused because I didn't know if #initialize method is called automatically. I use VisualAge 7.5 and I noticed, that if you create a new class using GUI (right-click, "new" -> "part...") and then save it, #initialize isn't called automatically! Even if you create a instance of your class in workspace. But if you export your class and then load it again, #initialize is called. To be more specific, class definition looks like this:

```
Object subclass: #InitTest
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''!

!InitTest class publicMethods !

initialize
Transcript show: 'initialize method'; cr.!
new 
Transcript show: 'new method'; cr.
^super new.! !

InitTest initialize! "<- it's created automatically"
InitTest initializeAfterLoad!
```

I think it's very tricky. Do you know how to (re)load a class definition in VisualAge workspace, to be sure that #initialize is called (without writing *InitTest initialize*)?

Comment: In Pharo, the typical way is to just send ``` InitTest initialize``` if the class was already loaded. Why do you want to avoid that? It's just for ease of development...

Comment: I think I understand your question now. The class-side #initialize is called when you load the class, or when you call it explicitly. The instance-side #initialize should be called from class-side #new. In Pharo, this is done automatically, but not in other dialects. For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692844/difference-between-new-and-initialize-in-smalltalk